# Daily average tiered fee

Tags: finance, average

Struggling to work out if this can be done.
Scenario: I am charging a client a daily fee using tiered fee rates

First $10,000,000 of value is charged 0.15%

Next $20,000,000 of value is charged at 0.10%

Anything over $30,000,000 is charged at 0.075%

Doing this daily is all well and good, but is there a way I can take an average of the daily values, over say a month, and return the same value as doing individual daily calculations and summing the answers together?

If the value is always above 30 million I have no issue. But what if the value dips below $30M - the arithmetic average of the daily values will no longer return the same value as individual daily calculations.

Comment: Do you have the information about the number of days for the three diifferent fee rates in a month?  This information is necessary.

Comment: If you are doing that many million dollars worth of business, then you can afford to hire a mathematical consultant to work out your arithmetic for you. Shame on you, trying to get people to work for you for free, while you rake in the millions.

Comment: @callculus I can't paste my example values in here (no good at using this website sorry)  my values are:  Day 1, 26,750,000.00    Day 2, 31,750,000.00    Day 3, 32,587,658.00    Day 4, 28,750,000.00    Day 5, 29,100,250.00    Day 6, 31,250,000.00

Comment: @GerryMyerson if you can help me out i'll go splitsies with you.

Comment: @AdamKR3000 Your comment doesn´t really answer my question.